# Best cryptography algorithm for short data sets in Android

Tags: java, android, algorithm, security, encryption

What is the best crypto algorithm (i.e. hardest to crack) to use when one has to encrypt short portions of data such as numeric (integer, long) for the Android platform ? I am looking for an encryption algorithm implemented on all phones using Android 1.6 and up and some implementation tutorial in Java preferably. Thanks.

Comment: No indication of original research. -1

Comment: what's the life span of those integers? if short you can use DES, maybe AES. Have you looked at RSA?

Comment: These are the available algorithms on my phones: [link]http://www.mediafire.com/?w5os6v2qq4g99u7[/link]

Comment: Should remain encrypted for the duration of an applications' life on the phone. I have looked at DES and AES briefly, not yet on RSA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For short data you are probably better off using something that doesn't need padding.  Either a good stream cypher or AES in CTR mode would do.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is short, e.g an int, you don't need a full blown encryption algorithm, just xor it with your secret (password). Typical encryption algorithms are needed when your data is significantly larger than your secret.